# Cannot send firebase push notification from lambda

Tags: node.js, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am hoping someone can help me point my mistake here.

I am trying to send a firebase push notification through a lambda using the HTTP legacy endpoint

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

I am following the guide from:
https://craigrussell.io/2019/03/send-firebase-fcm-push-notification-from-aws-lambda/

Here is my code:

```
const authHeader ='key=A****IV';
const deviceToken ='eut4****pm';
```

```
  console.log('sending Push notification');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      host: 'fcm.googleapis.com',
      path: '/fcm/send',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': authHeader,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log('success');
      resolve('success');
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.log('failuree' + e.message);
      reject(e.message);
    });

    // const reqBody = '{"to":"' + deviceToken + '", "priority" : "high"}';
    const reqBody = '{"to":"' + deviceToken + '", "priority": "high", "notification": {"title": "Test", "body": "Test"}}';
    console.log(reqBody);

    req.write(reqBody);
    req.end();
  });
};
```

I do not receive any push notification after this . Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key point is that you use the http module. Actually, it works well when using https module on my side.

```
var https = require('https');
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
var https = require('https');
exports.handler = async(event) => {
const authHeader = 'key=AA***y';
const deviceToken = 'fG***-';
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
        host: 'fcm.googleapis.com',
        path: '/fcm/send',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': authHeader,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    };

    console.log(options);
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(res.statusCode);
        resolve('success');
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log('failuree' + e.message);
        reject(e.message);
    });

    // const reqBody = '{"to":"' + deviceToken + '", "priority" : "high"}';
    const reqBody = '{"to":"' + deviceToken + '", "priority": "high", "notification": {"title": "Test", "body": "Test"}}';
    console.log(reqBody);

    req.write(reqBody);
    req.end();
});
};
```

For more details, you can see the res field after http request, it will show statusCode 403 when you use http.